# Three.js r87 combine textures

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have NxN matrix of textures (N=2):

```
-----------------
|       |       |
|  1,1  |  1,2  |
|       |       |
-----------------
|       |       |
|  2,1  |  2,2  |
|       |       |
-----------------
```

where textures are images loaded with:

```
var promises = [];
urls.forEach(function(url) {
    var deferred = async.defer();
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load(url, deferred.resolve);
    promises.push(deferred.promise);
});
// then textures are stored in 'textures' array
```

and `urls` is ordered array of url to retrieve images.

What I would obtain is a single `PlaneBufferGeometry` with a texture as a combination of alla textures, as showed above.

For now I'm creating NxN geometries, and then align them in the correct way, but I suppose that this is not the right way to do this.

Current version:

```
var geometries = [];
for (var i = 0; i < N*N; i++) {
    geometries.push(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(dim, dim, w, h));
}

for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometries[i * N + j], THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: textures[i * N + j] }));
        // ...now set mesh position accordingly with i and j
        scene.add(mesh);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about the **correct way**: one texture combined? one material with multiple textures? One mesh with multiple materials? Multiple geometries, then merged?

There are similar questions, but I have not found a solution for this case.

Thanks.

Comment: You could combine the textures on a canvas, then use that canvas as a texture on your material. [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/e6rbt3r4/) is an example that overlays 2 images to use as one texture.

Comment: thank you, really useful

Comment: For this specific use case, `WebGLRenderer.copyTextureToTexture` could also be used, see https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_texture_partialupdate.